# excel How to sum total working hours with positive and negative time

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have total hours worked in one row (see example below) with these values:

```
A1= 22:25, A2=-10:00, A3=3:00, A4=-4:45
```

(some time values are negative because employees didn't work the full shift).

The entries represent the hours and minutes works (e.g., A1: 22 hours 25 minutes)

So now all I want is to calculate total working hours like =SUM A1+A2+A3+A4= +-total working hours.  However, the cells are formated as text because Excel doesn't allow entering negative time.

Now I need to somehow sum up rows (formated as time) and convert it to time h:mm.

[image: example]

Comment: Are the cells formated as time?Have you tried `=SUM(A1:A4)`?

Comment: Cells are formated as text. Excel doesnt allow entering negative time. Now i need to somehow sum up rows (formated as time) and convert it to time h:mm

Comment: Are you sure the cell contents represent uniform measures of something?  People can't work negative time, so negative cells could represent a time shortage compared to scheduled hours.  But you can't add times worked to time shortages and get total time worked.  Are you just measuring overtime (adding excess hours to shortages to get net overtime)?  How should a net negative be handled?  Have you looked at custom formats rather than trying to do arithmetic on text values?

Comment: @Worda, how you are considering negative time, this should be subtracted from total time or what ?

Comment: Negative time represnts working hours that an emploey didnt worked out till his full shift. Both positive and negative numbers needs to be calculated and than converted to time format. Now i have changed the format of cells from text to decimal numbers and wrote it like this (22,25; -10,00; 3,00; -4,45) to do the calculation = 10,80 - now i need formula to turn this number into time because that would be 11 hours and 20 minutes. Now if i use the way some people suggested to have that number divide by 24 (10,80/24) and format it into time it gives me untrue result = 10:48

Comment: I believe i should use IF formulat that can figure it out when the number behind comma passes 60 (60 minutes) that it should turn it into 1 (1 hour) and add it to the number before comma. (result is 10,80 that means it is 11 hours and 20 minutes - due to the fact that after every 60minutes you add one hour and leaves you with the rest of the minutes).

Comment: @Worda,  I can suggest you one easier method SUM the +ve Hours nd Sum -ve hours then subtract, like ,`=(SUM(HOUR(A1),HOUR(C1)))`. Using your value I'm getting 11 Hrs. as answer !

Comment: Thnx! I have solve it :))

Comment: @Worda, did you solve using the method I've suggested or any other ?

Comment: You may be able to do arithmetic on the numbers, but it won't be correct.  The "minutes" will be parts of 100 instead of parts of 60, so they won't relate to hours correctly.  If you want a real answer, please respond to what was asked in the comments to clarify the problem (you just repeated information in the question without clarifying anything).  You're using methods for both your spreadsheet and your workaround that don't work when there are easy solutions that do.  (cont'd)

Comment: Of course, it's your problem and you are free to do it any way you like.  If you're happy with the spreadsheet and your solution, fine.  But in that case, please delete your question here because people in the community will waste their time trying to respond to your question and help you.

Comment: To clarify an earlier comment, if someone is supposed to work 40 hrs/wk, and one week they work 40 hrs and the next week they work 39 hrs, you can't get their total hours by adding 40 and -1.  And you **can** display negative times in Excel, so none of your workarounds are required.

Answer (score 11):

Ignoring what underlies the actual numbers, you have negative times that you want to display properly as negative times and be able to use for time arithmetic.  As workarounds, you tried formatting the times as text (complex to use in a math formula), and as decimal numbers (won't give the right answer unless you converted the minutes to hundredths of an hour).  None of that is required.

The formatting issue is specific the the "1900 basis" for handling dates/times.  The name comes from storing dates as the number of days since January 0, 1900.  Dates are then an integer day count, and times are stored as decimal fractions of a day.  So today at noon would be stored as 43286.5, and 3 hours is stored as 1/8th of a day, or 0.125.  The stored numbers are formatted to display in the readable form of your choice.

Since dates and times are stored as a single number, you can use it like any other number to do arithmetic without worrying about time units or other factors.  The 1900 basis happens to have a design restriction that doesn't allow negative times.

There is a built-in option to use a "1904 basis", which doesn't have the restriction on negative times.  That's actually the default on the Mac version.  With that you can display negative times and use them in calculations.  You can select it from the menu.  The route there varies with Excel version.  It is in the `Options` dialog.

In the 2007 version, it was via the Office button.  In the 2010, 2013, 2016, and 365 versions, it was via the `File` tab.  If the route has changed in newer versions, perhaps someone will be kind enough to add that to this answer.  From the Options dialog, select `Advanced`.  [One undated reference I just found that doesn't list the applicable version gives a route of `Tools » Options » Calculation`, so that's another one to try if the other routes don't match your version.]

[image]

Check `Use 1904 date system`, and `OK`.

Now you can store and display negative times as negative times, and do time math simply.  For example, just sum the times (regardless of positive or negative) to get the total.

Comment: Great info about the 1904 date system being able to display negative times. It vaguely rings a bell. I was probably aware of it years ago, but had completely forgotten about it. However, there is a big problem (at least in Excel 2007). While it displays negative times just fine, you cannot enter them directly. Trying to enter `-10:00` results in a generic *"The formula you typed contains an error."* dialog. You have to enter `10:00`, change the number format to General or Number, change the `0.416666666666667` to `-0.416666666666667`, and then change the number format back to a custom `h:mm`.

Comment: @robinCTS, interesting.  I use LO Calc and the version of Excel I have floating around is 2007, which probably not many current Excel users use.  I wonder if the same applies to recent versions.  If the OP's negative times result from a formula rather than direct entry, I assume that doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It's only when directly entering the negative times that Excel performs a "validation". Another way to enter a negative time directly would be to use a formula like `=-VALUE("10:00")`. You also have to explicitly set the number format to `h:mm` (or `[h]:mm`), though.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but I've got a simple fix which I worked out myself.
Write in an if statement to check which value is bigger, then subtract and format accordingly:
=IF(S3>P3,TEXT(SUM(S3-P3),"-[hh]:mm:ss"),TEXT(SUM(P3-S3),"[hh]:mm:ss"))
Explanation:

=IF(S3>P3,
Check which value is bigger

TEXT(SUM(S3-P3),"-[hh]:mm:ss")
If S is bigger, subtract P from S (which will always result in a number >0), then format it with the TEXT formula, adding a - at the start of the formatting.

,TEXT(SUM(P3-S3),"[hh]:mm:ss"))
If P is bigger, subtract S from P (which again will always result in a number >0), then format normally.

Comment: this only accounts for two times, the OP asks to add together a series of times, both negative and positive, and get a negative or positive result in the format hh:mm